# What is the equivalent of string conversion to US7ASCII in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to migrate the Oracle function

```
convert (UPPER('text'),'us7ascii')
```

to PostgreSQL. What is its equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

There is no perfect analogy, but you could try the `unaccent` function:

```
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;
SELECT unaccent(upper('schön'));
```